# Changing CSS-property of all elements in array

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, for-loop

I want to change `.style.backgroundColor` of all `<time>` elements within some `<div id="div">`. 
I resolved it like this:

```
var times = div.getElementsByTagName("time");
for (var i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
    times[i].style.backgroundColor = "#d00";
}
```

Is it possible to optimize the code so it will take as less variables as possible? Or maybe there is a way to do this with a single line?
P.S.: Using no JQuery;

Comment: No, in plain JS I don't think there is any alternate way without using a loop to traverse through all such elements.

Comment: @Harry I think OP didn't ask if there is any alternative way **without loop** he just asked more elegant way and without using jQuery

Comment: @Almis: Fair point. But I still think a loop is more readable and understandable from a layman perspective than slice, call and map. By no means deriding your answer, just a personal preference.

Comment: Your question contains a logical non sequitur, in that it implies that a jQuery solution could possibly be considered more elegant in the first place.

Comment: @torazaburo, I just don't know JQ. So the answer, based on it, won't help me :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about a practical problem with the code, but rather asking if there's a "better" way to write code that already works.

Comment: @Almis, It is too complex however. I should have to repeat this `.style.backgroundColor`-changing several times. Simple - is the best.

Comment: @DmitryParzhitsky My comment was in jest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In ES6 environments:

```
Array.from(div.querySelectorAll("time"), e => e.style.backgroundColor = "#d00");
```

This takes advantage of the ability of `Array.from` both to convert DOM node lists to arrays, **and** to take a second parameter which is a function to be applied to each element.

Comment: Just for understanding, is this better in terms of performance (or) better in terms of less lines of code? I think it would be a better answer if you could add some details on that too.

Comment: Cannot comment on performance, I strongly doubt there would be any major difference, and it probably doesn't matter. Yes, it's more compact, obviously.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying mate. I didn't know about this method and that is why wanted to check :)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to use a reverse `while` loop, like so:

```
var times=div.getElementsByTagName("time"),i=times.length;
while(i--)
    times[i].style.backgroundColor="#d00";
```

Comment: And the advantage of this is....??